# Backbone.js is not sending specific attributes to server within the paramRoot

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

If I save my code..

```
attrs = 
  attr1: 1
  attr2: 2
  attr3: 3

@question.save(attrs)
```

I have this in my backbone model:

```
url: '/questions'
paramRoot: 'question'
```

It will send to my server these params :

```
{question: {attr1: 1, attr2: 2} } # Note how it skips attr3
```

I am very specifically trying to update attributes that both do not exist in my original model but can be saved as such, and equally *not save other attributes* that are already instantiated with the object.

Comment: please post more code!

Comment: I'm not sure what I should I post. Its really simple. I try to save a specific attribute, and it only saves two attributes, and not the ones I'm passing in the argument.. Any recommendations on what else to post?

Comment: is your model `attrs`?

Comment: I don't understand.. *is your model `attrs`* . As in does it have `attrs` already? Yes, it does, it has many, yet only `attr1` and `attr2` are the only params that are sent within the `question` hash. Then everything else whether specified or not is sent without any hash.

Comment: Looks like my answer isn't too helpful. Where are you defining `@question`? What does that code look like?

Comment: Thanks for helping Evan :) There's really not much code to show.. What do you recommend me pasting? I can duplicate this by just doing any @model.save()

Comment: @Trip could you post the state of your model before the save method is applied? The list of attributes already there for a starter would be useful.

Comment: @Loamhoof that would include roughly 8 attributes in total including the first two that are properly included in the paramRoot. I've also found out that paramRoot isn't backbone but something included with backbone-rails. That's fine I can omit that if its possible to send just specific attributes, and not every attribute included in the model.

Comment: @Trip the paramRoot doesn't matter. So, roughly, it sends the intersection between what you're adding and what was already there?

Comment: My first thoughts was that it was an intersection, but it in truth it send attr1 and attr2 regardless of what I'm setting in the model beforehand. In fact, I can `@model.clear` and those attributes will still be saved to it after adding back exclusively four attributes ( including attr1 and attr2 ).

Comment: You know that `paramRoot` isn't a Backbone thing, right? That's some kludge that one of the Rails/Backbone gems sort of partially bolts on. What happens if you `.save(question: { ... })` instead?

Comment: Can you show us the code of your question model

Comment: @Mu, that was solid. You are still the ten time world champion of code. I will once again go and donate to a local animal shelter in your name. Thank you

Comment: Cheers brother, my rescue kitties thank you :)

Comment: try this one https://coderwall.com/p/je4bfa or include https://raw.github.com/codebrew/backbone-rails/master/vendor/assets/javascripts/backbone_rails_sync.js jscript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In javascript, you'd do something like:

```
var QuestionModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot = "/questions"
});

question = new QuestionModel();
question.set('attr1', 1);
question.set('attr2', 2);
question.set('attr3', 3);

question.save();
```

Or you can save and add the attributes at once:

```
question.save({
    attr1: 1,
    attr2: 2,
    attr3: 3
});
```

Comment: It does not save those attributes though. It only saves two of the three. And by save, its sending only two of the attributes in my `paramRoot: 'question'` and the rest return outside of that paramRoot

Comment: @Trip i'm not sure about `url` vs `urlRoot` but in this case I think you want urlRoot as it's outside of a Collection. in addition, what is paramRoot?